# How to match 1 character in a string

Tags: java, regex, string, character, match

Im writing code for a password policy.

Policy says that you can't have the same letter that you already used.
Ex: password - you cant use password because it has two 's'

How can I do that?

EDIT:

Here's my full implementation:

```
private static final String PASSWORD_DUPLICATE_CHARACTERS = "^(?:([a-zA-Z])(?!.*\\1))$";

pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_DUPLICATE_CHARACTERS);
this.checkForDuplicateLetters(LDAPNewUserPassword);

private boolean checkForDuplicateLetters(final String newPassword) throws LDAPException{
    LoggingEnt userEnt = new LoggingEnt();
    String userid = userEnt.getUseridCode();
    boolean foundDuplicate = false;

    matcher = pattern.matcher(newPassword);

    if (newPassword.matches(PASSWORD_DUPLICATE_LETTERS)){
        foundDuplicate = true;
        userEnt.setMsg1("Duplicate.");
        throw new LDAPException("Invalid password combination for " + userid, LDAPException.INVALID_CREDENTIALS);//BAristo
    } else {
        userEnt.setMsg1("Your password has been successfully changed.");
    }

    return matcher.matches();
```

}

Comment: Is that your only restriction? Or are you implementing several restrictions in separate rules?

Comment: It should probably be mentioned that this is not a good idea for a password policy, as it drastically cuts down the search space.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker no. I have broken it down to several sequences in order to keep the code readable for other programmers that would take my place once I'm gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN_LOWER_8 = "^(?:([a-zA-Z])(?!.*\\1))$";
```

Comment: The good thing about this regex is that it will find repeated letters anywhere in the string. On the other hand, it now only allows letters in the password, and even allows the empty string...

Comment: Good point, though you can also add more characters in the matching character class as well as the minimum number of matches. I was showing the regex without additional restrictions based on the OP question.

Comment: The lower case letters were not read even if there was no duplicate letter. Help me please. Is there another way?

Comment: works for me. this regex also has 6 character minimum limit for password. remove {6,} if you don't need it.

Comment: 'Pasw70rd' and 'password' failed on the regex you gave. One has no duplicate, and the other one has, yet both failed.

Comment: both work for me. Is this java? You need to escape backslashes. I added full line.

Comment: @gramonov Yes this is Java. I'm quite new to regex and still confused. I modified your code to only check for upper and lower case, since I don't need to check letters for duplicates.

Will this one work?


`private static final String PASSWORD_DUPLICATE_LETTER = "^(?:([a-zA-Z])(?!.*\\1))$";`

Comment: Yep, it should work. I've updated the answer to match what you want exactly, i.e. only letters and no limit on number of characters.

Comment: Weird. How come it works with you but does not work with me. Im already using the regex you gave me.

 `private static final String PASSWORD_DUPLICATE_CHARACTERS = "^(?:([a-zA-Z])(?!.*\\1))$";`

It does not fulfill the conditions in:
`if (newPassword.matches(PASSWORD_DUPLICATE_CHARACTERS)){
      foundDuplicate = true;
      userEnt.setMsg1("Duplicate.");
      throw new LDAPException("Invalid password combination for " + userid, LDAPException.INVALID_CREDENTIALS);//BAristo
     } else {
      userEnt.setMsg1("Your password has been successfully changed.");
     }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as follows:

```
<snip> PASSWORD_PATTERN_LOWER_8 = "(?i)^(?!.*(.).*\\1)";
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?i)  # Case-insensitive mode
^     # Match start of string (might be redundant, but won't hurt either)
(?!   # Assert that it's impossible to match...
 .*   # any string
 (.)  # that's followed by one character (captured into group 1)
 .*   # followed by any string
 \\1  # and a repetition of the character we captured before.
)     # End of lookahead
```

Performance will not be that great, especially with longer strings, because in the worst case, every character will have to be compared with every other character.

For example, the password `.qwertzuiopasdfghjklöäyxcvbnm,.` will only be detected as invalid after over 1000 steps of the regex engine, whereas `qwertzuiopasdfghjklöäyxcvbnm,..` would fail immediately.

It might be a better idea to sort the string first and look for directly subsequent characters:

```
<snip> PASSWORD_PATTERN_LOWER_8 = "(?i)^(?!.*(.)\\1)";
```

Comment: It does not have to be subsequent identical characters. Another example would be 'Sister'. If 'S' is already used, it can no longer be used.

Answer (score 0):

i would use something like this

```
^((.)(?!.*\1))+$
```

This would match string that has no repeated character anywhere in the string